# Linq to Entities, Take(3) from Joined table

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to populate a ViewModel in an MVC app with data from a parent table joined with a child table. The only data I want from the child table is a comma diliminated string from the Nomenclature field of the top three records and put them into a string field in the ViewModel. Here is what I have tried without success:

```
public IEnumerable<ReqHeaderVM> GetOpenReqs(string siteCode)
    {
      var openReqs = from h in context.ReqHeaders
      join l in context.ReqLineItems on h.ID equals l.ReqID into reqLineItems
       select new ReqHeaderVM
       {
         ReqID = h.ID,
         ShopCode = h.ShopCode
         Nomenclatures = reqLineItems.Select(x => x.Nomenclature).Take(3) // This doesn't work

       };
        return (openReqs.ToList());
    }
```

Here is the ViewMdel:

```
    public class ReqHeaderVM
{
    [Editable(false)]
    public string ReqID { get; set; }
    public string ShopCode { get; set; }
    public string  Nomenclatures {get; set;}


}
```

Comment: Have you noted you use x.Nomenclature and Nomenclatures? Is simple but sometimes this things will broke code. Do you use in database the field Nomenclature without the "s"?

Comment: @Jason, yes I use Nomenclatures in the ViewModel and expect to stuff in it the top 3 fields called Nomenclature from the ReqLineItems table. I will be using this in a grid to show the user all the open orders they have and by including the first 3 Nomenclatures from the line items table into one field, they will be able to easily recognize which order is which.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have proper relationship (foreign key) between ReqHeaders and ReqLineItems, this should give you what you are looking for...

```
public IEnumerable<ReqHeaderVM> GetOpenReqs(string siteCode)
{
    var openReqs = from h in context.ReqHeaders
                    select new
                    {
                        ReqID = h.ID,
                        ShopCode = h.ShopCode
                        Nomenclatures = h.ReqLineItems
                            .OrderBy(x => x.SomeColumn)
                            .Select(x => x.Nomenclature)
                            .Take(3)
                    };

    var openReqsTran = from oreq in openReqs.AsEnumerable()
                        select new ReqHeaderVM
                        {
                            oreq.ReqID,
                            oreq.ShopCode,
                            Nomenclatures = string.Join(", ", oreq.Nomenclatures)

                        };

    return (openReqsTran);
}
```

Note that Nomenclatures is a list of type of Nomenclature.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your solution and I get the same error as with my solution: An instance of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' can not be assigned to a member of type 'string'. I don't want Nomenclatures to be a list at all, I want it to be a string with just three nomenclatures which are comma dilimintated. So if the order has 10 line items, I only want to show the first three items nomenclature in the Nomenclatures field like so : Widget1, Widget2, Widget3.

Comment: Updated. This is to be done in two steps as the join code can't be performed in SQL without a custom DB specific function.

Comment: @amit_g: `ReqHeaderVM.Nomenclatures` is of type string, so you actually want to use anonymous objects on the db side and `ReqHeaderVM`s on the client side.

Comment: OK, I'm getting closer to a solution. I have also posted a similar question in the MSDN forum and have a partial solution. Since I can't seem to add any code to a comment I will provide a link.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/38c11cca-fa0a-46c5-a6d9-04970f14b343

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the join creates a single Cartesian result set. (think tabular data) what you are attempting to do. To get the results you want you have a few choices.

1. use lazy loading and iterate over each header querying the line items individually.

   1. pro - simple queries
   2. con - select n+1
2. query all headers and all line items, but build view model with only the top 3

   1. pro - single query
   2. con - large Cartesian result set query too much data
3. query all headers and all associated lines individuals

   1. pro - 2 smaller, simpler queries
   2. con - query too many line details.
4. query all headers and top 3 lines per header in 2 queries

   1. pro - get only the information you require
   2. con - complex query for top 3 lines per header.